# Tag-free garbage collection for object oriented languages

Tags: programming-languages, compilers, memory-management, empirical-research, garbage-collection

I'm looking around for a good garbage collection technique for my [language](https://github.com/MathiasVP/Alpha) and found [this paper](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/goldberg/pubs/gold91.pdf), where Benjamin Goldberg describes a garbage collection technique for strongly typed languages, which removes the need for type information during runtime.

Briefly, this is done by placing a pointer to a garbage collection function right after a function call, directly in the compiled code. They then extend this to support ML-like parametric polymorphism.

**Now my question**: Has there been any work on how this technique could be implemented in an object oriented language, where much functionality is implemented through indirect calls using pointers in a virtual table?

Comment: What do you see as being a problem? What matters is that each entity knows its own storage identity.

Comment: Yes, but in my scenario it's not known at compile-time which function is called, and thus the gc_routine (terminology from the paper) to call during garbage collection is not known at compile-time. I'm looking for a solution to this problem, without resorting to an interpreted GC method.

Comment: I tried to answer your question, as made more precise in the comment,
but I am wondering if that is really the problem you have in mind. Comments are welcome.

Comment: it sounds like you simply need runtime indirection in the gc system that matches the function indirection. note there are many garbage collection schemes, its just a matter of finding one that matches your language design....

Answer (score 7):

Like [Häagen-Dazs ice-cream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A4agen-Dazs), Object Orientation comes in many flavor,
though with more nuts and bananas. Hence it is hazardous to answer
your question stated in very general terms. Specific OO languages
could have unexpected features that might raise problems with virtual
methods. I fear that trying to imagine what kind of features could make
things go wrong is a bit of a fruitless exercise. It is better to try
answering precise questions.

The basic principle of tag-free GC is that, at any time, you should be
able to inspect the memory starting from the stack, and know the
actual type of all chunks of live allocated memory (because that is
precisely what the GC will need to work). This implies also to know,
at each call point of a function/method, the current state of
activation block of the caller, whether on the stack or on the heap,
i.e. the current variables of the block and their state of
initialisation. The necessary structural information can be stored as
data descriptors to be interpreted, or as executable *gc-routines* for
better GC efficiency. The important point of tag-free GC is that this
information can be determined statically, in order to be stored once
with the code rather than with each instance of a type or class or of
function activation. When this information can change dynamically, as
is the case with polymorphic types, it must be possible to compute it
by tracing and compounding static type information through the dynamic
call sequence.

The fact that a method is virtual and called through a virtual table
is not in itself a problem. **A caller does not need to know what it is
calling as it has no importance regarding GC for its own activation
record**. The callee is supposed to know itself (the compiler sees to
it), and carry whatever information it need. The information may be
incomplete as in the case of polymorphism, and must be completed from
other type information available in the call sequence. Actually, in
a language like ML, where functions can be passed as parameters, or put
in tuples, the
caller may not know what function it is actually calling.

**What matters is that the caller knows where in its code it calls the
callee, so as to determine the state of its activation block during
the call. This is
statically dependent on the call point, and can thus be inferred from
the callee return address**,(in various ways depending on technical
variations used by different authors). The corresponding `gc-routine`
can thus be found in some way from that return address. For example,
it can be in the code right after the call, but other equivalent
techniques could be considered. So if the callee is interupted by
GC, it will be possible to do the GC for the callers activation
record. **The caller does no GC work for the callee, only for its own
activation record.**

*What may be a problem* is making sure that the callee does know the
actual type of all the values that are passed to it (as in polymorphism).
More precisely, it must be possible to find that information when the
GC occurs and must deal with the activation record of the actual
method that is access through a virtual.

I believe that being more precise on this last issue is dependent on the actual features
and classe/objects structures of the OO language, on its typing
organization.

But, as the caller does not need to know the callee, I do not see that
indirect calls can be a problem.

Another point (answering the OP's comment) is that the issue here is
not whether GC is performed from compiled code or interpreted from
descriptors, but whether it needs dynamic tag for type information.

**Suggestion**: to find more work on this, take your favorite search
engines (and other web resources) and look for papers
citing the Goldberg papers or its mains references. Apply the
procedure recursively, adding occasional keywords such as *object
oriented* or *virtual*.